# Creating table captions for Word document from Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm in the process of automating a document generator from an Excel spreadsheet using VBA. I've managed to create a few tables in the document, but I can't seem to add a caption and caption label to the tables. I've tried using the captionlabel object, which is what is used in Word, but it says that the function or sub is not defined.

Set objword=createobject("word.application")
Set objdoc=objword.documents.add

Objword.selection.tables.add range:=wrdrange, numrows:=(num+4), numvolumns:=7

Set objtable = objdoc.tables(1)

Sorry very new to posting and vba.

Comment: Did you try recording the macro as you do this manually?

Comment: @AnalystCave.com I've tried doing that in Word and found the captionlabel object, which does not seem to work in excel vba

Comment: Please share your current code.